# insert() работает очень странно, переписывал несколько раз и почти тоже самое. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я выполняю задание и столкнулся с тем, что инсерт, по непонятной причине дублирует кучу раз, то что надо сделать один раз. Задача изначально такая:

> 2. Дан список: ['в', '5', 'часов', '17', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '+5', 'градусов'] Необходимо его обработать —
>    обособить каждое целое число кавычками и дополнить нулём до двух
>    разрядов: ['в', '"', '05', '"', 'часов', '"', '17', '"', 'минут',
>    'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '"', '+05', '"', 'градусов'] Новый
>    список не создавать! Сформировать из обработанного списка строку: в
>    "05" часов "17" минут температура воздуха была "+05" градусов.

Сначала код выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее я меняю его на этот:

```
arr = ['в', '5', 'часов', '17', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '+5', 'градусов']

for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i].isdigit() == True :
        print(i, " =  i")
        val_1 = i + 1
        print("Первый вал, те i + 1 =", val_1)
        arr.insert(val_1, '"')
    # if arr[i].isdigit() == True :
    #     print(i, " =  i")
    #     
    #     arr.insert(i, '"')
```

Ситуация не особо стала лучше, потому что вывод теперь такой:

```
['в', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '5', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', 'часов', '17', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '+5', 'градусов']
```

Даже если мы закоментим, то что я закоментим тут, результат нормальный(все рвано это не то что нужно):

```
['в', '5', '"', 'часов', '17', '"', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '+5', 'градусов']
```

Помогите, я не понимаю, где тут проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `insert` добавляет элемент, смещая позиции следующих элементов, поэтому нужно корректировать индексы и отказаться от `range(len(arr))`, т.к. размер будет меняться.

Вместо этого, вручную меняйте индекс и используйте `while`

Попробуйте

```
def get_sign(x):
    if x[0] in '+-':
        return x[0]

arr = ['в', '5', 'часов', '17', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '+5', 'градусов']

i = 0
while i < len(arr):
    sign = get_sign(arr[i])
    if arr[i].isdigit() or (sign and arr[i][1:].isdigit()):
        if sign:
            arr[i] = sign + arr[i][1:].zfill(2)
        else:
            arr[i] = arr[i].zfill(2)

        arr.insert(i, '"')
        arr.insert(i + 2, '"')
        i += 2

    i += 1

print(arr)
# ['в', '"', '05', '"', 'часов', '"', '17', '"', 'минут', 'температура', 'воздуха', 'была', '"', '+05', '"', 'градусов']
```

Comment: простите, а для чего тут zfill() и что делает get_sign?

Comment: @Август, zfill добавляет слева 0 до указанной в него длины, а `get_sign` функция для получения знака первого символа, чтобы отличать числа, например: `+5`, `-5` и `5`